# Webpack 2: compile SASS and ignore "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/image.png'"

Tags: css, sass, webpack, webpack-2

I'm trying to use Webpack instead of Gulp as a task runner, in this case simply compiling all SCSS files as I was doing it with Compass before. The main objectives are:

1. run Autoprefixer and generate separate CSS file for each SCSS that is not a partial
2. don't bundle images or concatenate CSS files
3. keep image urls as is, e.g. `background-image: url(assets/image.png)`
4. don't throw errors if images cannot be found

**#1 is solved and working**, however it stops working and throws an error as soon as the SCSS links to an image as in #3 above:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./scss/style.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/image.png' in 'C:\Users\robro\projects\...\my-project\dev\styles\scss
@ ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./scss/style.scss 6:15328-15369
@ ./scss/style.scss
```

I'd like to "simply" ignore that error and not having to copy the missing files to my local hard drive. That's mostly just me being stubborn, thinking *"Compass didn't need those images to be present, why does Webpack?"*

Here's my setup:

---

`webpack.config.js`

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

var ExtractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name]');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'style.css': './scss/style.scss',
        'admin.css': './scss/admin.scss'
    },
    output: {
        filename: './css/[name]'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractCSS.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: [
                        "css-loader",
                        "postcss-loader",
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                })
            },
            { test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg|gif|woff|woff2|otf|ttf)$/, use: 'ignore-loader' }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        ExtractCSS
    ],
    watch: true
};
```

---

`package.json`

```
{
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.3",
        "ignore-loader": "^0.1.2",
        "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^1.3.0",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
        "webpack": "^2.2.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0"
    }
}
```

---

As you can see, i tried using `ignore-loader` to stop `sass-loader` from complaining about missing images, but to no avail. To be honest, I'm not even sure this is how it's intended to be used.

As soon as I remove any line that links to images from the SCSS, everything is working just fine: `style.css` and `admin.css` get built, autoprefixed and dropped into `css/` folder. Now I want to keep it that way, but also use styles like `background-image: url(assets/image.png)` without webpack complaining about those images not being present on the file system.

Comment: why don't you just use url-loader/file-loader and actually load the images?—I don't understand why you're using images in your CSS files that you don't want/need...

Comment: Maybe I could / should. I guess I'm trying to do things in a way that Webpack isn't meant to do. Setting this up with Gulp took 30 minutes and it doesn't complain about missing images. And it shouldn't imho, unless I'm explicitly running some kind of "check all my assets" command - which Webpack has built-in. This is merely intended to be a proof of concept, getting a grasp of the differences between tools.

Comment: webpack is not meant to do the same thing that gulp does.

Comment: That's exactly what I've come to realize in the meantime. Thanks for taking the time :)

Comment: Simply do this in Webpack3 (should work for WP2 as well): 
`module: {
        rules: [
            (...),
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
                    use: ['css-loader?url=false', 'sass-loader']
                })
            }
        ]
    },`
The part you need is the `?url=false`: this tells the loader to not process urls found, meaning it won't process files (images, and so on).

Comment: @RuiCarvalho, setting `?url=false` helped me! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Case closed: Webpack is NOT a task runner. Blog posts naming Webpack as a successor to Grunt or Gulp or  fail to explicitly point out that these tools may have some overlapping features but in the end have very different goals. Grunt and Gulp are task runners and Webpack is an asset bundler. Trying to make Webpack **not** bundle your assets defeats it's main purpose and one's better off choosing a different tool.

Comment: Try reading the official documentation of Loaders for Wepack (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/) specifically where it says:

_Loaders are transformations that are applied on the source code of a module. They allow you to pre-process files as you import or “load” them. Thus, loaders are kind of like “tasks” in other build tools, and provide a powerful way to handle front-end build steps._ 

and then let us know if you still think the same.